# How to chain where clause with multiple `==`s , multiple `>=`, multiple `<=` range filters

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2, querying

I need to get data of 'things': 'Animals', 'type': 'Mammals', 'dob' >= startDate and 'dbo' <= endDate

Is that possible to query like
`ref.where('things', '==', 'Animals').where('type', '==', 'Mammals').where('dob', '>=', startDate).where('dob', '<=', endDate)`

The range filter works with single `==` and not more than one `==`.
Is that possible to query like above? Or any other alternate way to achieve it?

Comment: Cloud Firestore can only apply a range filter on a single field, but can have equality filters on many fields. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries What is the problem when you run the query you've shown?

Comment: Its not run thats the problem. When I comment one of the equality where clause it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation here https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

Says that to combine an equality with a range you need to create a composite index.

I imagine your query will work as you are only doing a range query on one field but you will need to create a composite index to do that.

You can read more about creating composite indexes here https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing

As pointed out by AndrewHill in the comments. It looks like firestore will allow you to automatically create a composite index after the first time you try to query it. So this should definitely help out where needed.

Comment: It's worth noting that you do not need to manually create a composite index in the firebase console. If you execute a composite query from your app without creating an index first; firebase will error out in the console and provide you with a URL to auto-generate the composite index for you.

Comment: Here is an example of firebase generating a composite index for you in the console: https://i.imgur.com/fqPUvAB.jpg

Comment: @everyone Thank you very much. Works like a fruit. :kiwifruit:

And `It looks like firestore will allow you to automatically create a composite index after the first time you try to query it` :thumbsup:

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Firestore can only apply a range filter on a single field, but can have equality filters on many fields. See the [documentation on compound queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries) for examples and explanation.

Since the only range filter you have is on `dob`, your query should be possible. You will need to define a composite index on `things`, `type`, and `dob` to allow the query. If you don't have that index, the Firestore client will log an error in the console output. If you click the link in that error message, you'll be taken straight to the index creation screen with the form already filled out with the correct information for the index that is required.

Comment: Composite indexing helps me to solve the issue. Thank you very much @frank